# how to test the locally created plugin in grails

Tags: grails, grails-plugin

I have created a local plugin as "localPlugin" in grails. While running the plugin project as `grails -Dserver.port=7071 run-app` from terminal. It runs successfully as

```
| Running Grails application
| Server running. Browse to address:7071/localPlugin
```

How to test the `localPlugin` before I include it in another web project in grails?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you mean by *test*. Typically this would be done using unit and integration tests. However, from your question it would seem you want to test it within an application.

You have two options.

1. Create an application and include your plugin and test it through that application.
2. Try out the ["Test apps" plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/testapps).

Most authors of plugins create a sample test application to test their plugin within. If they need functional tests or to test the lifecycle events of the plugin.

Comment: Didn't know about test apps plugin. Thanks for pointing that out. :)

Comment: Haven't had a chance to use it yet, but it looks promising.

Comment: First impression at the github pages looks like it works on the principle of Travis CI builds which provisions testing against different version of fw simultaneously.